# IF statement with INSERT INTO, the mysql syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do a mysql expression, but something is wrong or everything is wrong : D

// mysql

```
    DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION create_channel2 (a1 varchar(35) ,a2 INT(11) ,a3 INT(10))
RETURNS INT(10) DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN

IF INSERT INTO channel_table (name) VALUES(al) THEN 
return LAST_INSERT_ID(); END IF
return 0;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should learn about the difference between [MySql Control Flow Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html) and C# control flow instructions.  You are mixing them in the wrong place, or you are trying to execute commands that belong in [Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-programs-views.html)